# Using XLDOWN in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that generates a pivot table and pastes it into a sheet. I want to do some calculations on the data in that table and then create a chart off of those calculations. Currently I have the VBA below and it has worked fine but the pivot table has started to have a varying number of rows rather than always 48. I want to be able to dynamically generate the chart no matter how many rows the pivot table ends up having. The pivot table data will always start in A64 (with headers in A63 that I don't need) and it has a grand total at the bottom which I don't want so I guess I'll have to use xldown - 1 or something similar. There are multiple tables on the sheet but there are spaces between them.

I think I need to use End XLDOWN in this case but I'm not sure exactly how to do it. Can anyone help?

```
Range("Pivots!$E64).Formula = "=((C64/B64)/DATA!$Y$5)"
 Range("Pivots!$E65).Formula = "=((C65/B65)/DATA!$Y$5)"

 ... and so on down to 

 Range("Pivots!$E111).Formula = "=((C111/B111)/DATA!$Y$5)"

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivots!$E$64:$E$111")
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Pivots!$A$64:$A$111"

 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
 ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
 ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
 Sheets("Front Sheet").Select

 Range("B23").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: See this post about [using xlUp and xlDown](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) either in tables or in spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the row of the pivot table end with:

```
Dim LRow as Long
LRow = Sheets("Pivots").Range("B3").End(XLDown).Row -1
```

You can then use the LRow variable to represent the last row of the pivot table. You'll want to use a loop for setting your formulas, like Dim LLoop As Long

```
For LLoop = 64 To LRow
    Sheets("Pivots").Range("$E" & LLoop).Formula = "=((C" & LLoop & "/B" & LLoop & ")/DATA!$Y$5)"
Next LLoop
```

Finally, you can set the source data and XValues of your Pivot Chart using the same LRow variable.

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Pivots").Range("$E$64:$E$" & LRow)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Pivots!$A$64:$A$" & LRow
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I'm getting an error at this line

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Pivots").Range("$E$64:$E$" & LRow)

it says 
Run-time error '91':
object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: @tomdemaine Try using `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivots!$E$64:$E$" & LRow)`

Comment: Same issue I'm afraid

Comment: You know what, I missed out ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select my bad. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting each formula individually, you can just use the [`.FillDown` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx).

```
With wsPivots
    lastPivotRow = .Range("E64").End(xlDown).Row - 1
    .Range("E64").Formula = "=((C64/B64)/DATA!$Y$5)"
    .Range("E64:E" & lastPivotRow).FillDown
End With
```

As explained by @[Nick Peranzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5472502/nick-peranzi), you can assign a variable with the last row of the pivot data and then use this in your code.

It's also worthwhile mentioning, that when working with objects in VBA, it improves the speed if you take advantage of the [`With...End With` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

```
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Pivots!$E$64:$E$" & lastPivotRow)
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Pivots!$A$64:$A$" & lastPivotRow
End With
```